# Don't understand how to update React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've tried to ask this ungooglable to me question dozens of times. I've made almost the simpliest example possible to ask this question now.

I change the value of the hook in the `handleChange` method. But then `console.log` always shows previous value, not new one. Why is that?

I need to change the value of the hook and then instead of doing `console.log` use it to do something else. But I can't because the hook always has not what I just tried to put into it.

```
const options = ["Option 1", "Option 2"];

export default function ControllableStates() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(options[0]);

  const handleChange = val => {
    setValue(val);
    console.log(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{value}</div>
      <br />
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          handleChange(newValue);
        }}
        options={options}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" variant="outlined" />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can try it here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-lumiere-y2dww?file=/src/App.js

Comment: when you call `setValue(val)` you internally set the new value, however the variable `value` does not change anymore, it always holds a copy of the latest value when `useState` was called. At this point you can think of `value` as an immutable variable, it will never change. Put the `console.log` outside the handler and you'll see that every time your component function get executed, the value will change **after** `handleCgange` is called.

Comment: I need to change the value of the hook and then instead of doing console.log use it to do something else. How do I achieve this then? How can I use the new value of my component right away?

Comment: I think you are understanding how hooks and component works wrong. Every time the component function is executed, it's just a "snapshot" of the latest state. React will render the component when a) input change or b) state change. Calling the setter function make a state change. However you can only see the new state in the next call of the component function. You are actually doing it right, just call `setValue` and React will take care of rendering your component again, at which point you'll see the change. You can see that `<div>{value}</div>` has the correct value after...

Comment: you set something else, so this shows it's working correctly. Realize that the `value` variable is a `const`, it's immutable, once set it cannot change.

Comment: ok, I get it, but I don't understand how to use users input then. After selecting something in this component, user presses the button and the button needs to use currently selected value

Comment: The button will just reference `value` and it will get the latest one, because React will render the component when the state changes. So `<button value={value}</button>` is more than enough. When the handler executes `setValue(val)`, React will render the component again at which point React will realize that the inputs of `<button>` changed, which will make React render `<button>` again, thus passing the latest version of `value`. In your example this already happens with the `<div>{value}</div>`. I recommend that you read this again https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, lets get a little back and see the logic behind this scenario.
You should use the "handleChange" function ONLY to update the state hook, and let something else do the logic depends on that state hook value, which is mostly accomplished using "useEffect" hook.

You could refactor your code to look like this:

```
  const handleChange = val => {
    setValue(val);
   };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(value);
    // do your logic here
  }, [value])
```

Comment: ok, lets say I have two different Autocomplete components using two different hooks. Can I create two useEffect hooks?

Comment: ok, that kinda helps, but I still have a problem. After I selected something in the Autocomplete component I need to press a button, which has to use selected value. Don't understand how to do that

Comment: Check out this codesandbox example, i updated it, 
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-tree-fd7r7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark
If it answers your question, please accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are logging the value in the `handleChange` function. Console logging the value outside of the function logs the correct value. Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/async-fast-6y71b

Comment: It is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Hooks do not *instantly* update the value you want to update, as you might have expected with classes (though that wasn't guaranteed either)

State hook, when calling `setValue` will trigger a re-render. In that new render, the state will have the new value as you expected. That's why your `console.log` *sees* the old value.

Think of it as in each render, the state values are just *local variables* of that component function call. And think as the result of your render as a result of your state + props in that render call. Whenever any of those two changes (the props from your parent component; the state, from your *setXXX* function), a new render is triggered.

If you move out the `console.log` *outside* of the callback handler (that is, in the body of your rendered), there you will see in the render that happens after your interaction that the state is logged correctly.

In that sense, in your callbacks events from interactions, you just should worry about updating your state properly, and the next render will take care to, given the new props/state, re-render the result

Comment: I need to change the value of the hook and then instead of doing console.log use it to do something else. How do I achieve this then? How can I use the new value of my component right away?

Answer (score 0):

The value doesn't "change" synchronously - it's even declared with a `const`, so even the concept of it changing inside the same scope doesn't make sense.

When changing state with hooks, the new value is seen *when the component is rerendered*. So, to log and do stuff with the "new value", examine it in the main body of the function:

```
const ControllableStates = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(options[0]);

  const handleChange = val => {
    setValue(val);
  };
  // ADD LOG HERE:
  console.log('New or updated value:', value);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{value}</div>
      <br />
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          handleChange(newValue);
        }}
        options={options}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" variant="outlined" />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I need to change the value of the hook and then instead of doing console.log use it to do something else. How do I achieve this then? How can I use the new value of my component right away?

Comment: The component doesn't re-render immediately - it's asynchronous. What exactly do you need to do with it that replacing `console.log` with the real implementation is causing problems?

Comment: as soon as I change the state of Autocomplete I have to use its new state to send a request

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out the old `value` in `handleChange`, not the new `val`.
i.e.

```
  const handleChange = val => {
    setValue(val);
    console.log(value);
  };
```

Should be:

```
  const handleChange = val => {
    setValue(val);
    console.log(val);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think that the main problem is that you're not understanding how React
deals with components and states.

So, I'll vastly simplify what React does.

- React renders a new component and remembers it's state, it's inputs (aka
  props) and it's the state and inputs of the children.
- If at any given point an input changes or a state changes, React will render
  the component again by calling the component function.

Consider this:

```
function SomeComponent(text) {
    return (<div>The <i>text</i> prop has the value {text}</div>)
}
```

Let's say the initial prop value is `"abc"`, React will call `SomeComponent("abc")`, then the function returns
`<div>The <i>text</i> prop has the value abc</div>` and React will render that.
If the prop `text` does not change, then React does nothing anymore.

Now the parent component changes the prop to `"def"`, now React will call
`SomeComponent("def")` and it will return
`<div>The <i>text</i> prop has the value def</div>`, this is different from
last call, so React will update the DOM to reflect the change.

Now let's introduce state

```
function SomeComponent() {
    const [name, setName] = React.useState("John")

    function doSomething()
    {
        alert("The name is " + name)
    }

    return (
        <p>Current name: {name}</p>
        <button onClick={() => setName("Mary")}>Set name to Mary</button>
        <button onClick={() => setName("James")}>Set name to James</button>
        <button onClick={() => doSomething()}>Show current name</button>
    )
}
```

So here React will call `SomeComponent()` and render the name *John* and the 3
button. Note that the value of the `name` variable does not change during the
current execution, because it's declared as `const`. This variable only reflects
the latest value of the state.

When you press the first button, `setName()` is executed. React will internally store
the new value for the state and because of the change of state, it will render
the component again, so `SomeComponent()` will be called once again. Now the variable `name` will
reflect again the latest value of the state (that's what `useState`does), so in this case *Mary*. React
will realize that the DOM has to be updated and it prints the name *Mary*.

If you press the third button, it will call `doSomething()` which will print the
latest value of the `name` variable because every time React calls
`SomeComponent()`, the `doSomething()` function is created again with the latest
value of `name`. So once you've called `setName()`, you don't need to do
anything special to get the new value. React will take care of calling the
component function again.

So when you don't use class components but function components, you have to think
differently: the function gets called all the time by React and at any single
execution it reflects the latest state at that particular point in time. So when you
call the setter of a `useState` hook, you know that the component function will
be called again and `useState` will return the new value.

I recommend that you read [this article](https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/), also read again [Components and
Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) from the React documentation.

So how should you do proceed? Well, like this:

```
const options = ["Option 1", "Option 2"];

export default function ControllableStates() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(options[0]);

  const handleChange = val => {
    setValue(val);
    console.log(value);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
      // DOING SOMETHING WITH value
      alter(`Now I'm going to do send ${value}`);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{value}</div>
      <br />
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          handleChange(newValue);
        }}
        options={options}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" variant="outlined" />
        )}
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Send selected option</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-cartwright-yt076).